# How did shiva get the name Trikagni kaala?

Tags: shiva, name, shiva-mahimna-stotra

Shiva stotram has a beautiful stanza at the ending which goes:

> Namaste astu bhagwan vishweshwaraya, mahadevaya, tryambakya, tripurantakaya, **TRIKAGNIKALAYA**, kalagni rudraya, neelkanthaya, mrityunjayaya, sarveshwaraya, sadashivaya, sriman mahadevaya namah

So, my question is how did Shiva get the name of trikagnikalaya? Does it have to do anything with mastering three agnis in the human body? Please elaborate.

Comment: Its NOT related to Shiva-Mahimna-Stotra i think.So you can drop that tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name ((Trika-Agni-KAla, from which the word TrikAgnikAlaya is derived by chaturthi vibhakti) consists three words: Trika, Agni and KAla.According to the sanskritdictionary.com, Trika means three types. And Agni is of three types:

> (Sacrificial) fire of three kinds : Garhpatya. Ahavaniya and Dakshina (गार्हपत्य, आहवनीय and दक्षिण);

The word 'Tika' besides meaning three types has other deep connotations. According to the TantrAloka

> trkam sAram chid-IshA -uNmesha-Atmakam, meaning : Trika means Chit(consciousnes), Ichha(Willingness) and Unmesha(Unfolding). These three are also referred to as ParA, aparA, and ParApara shaktis of Lord Shiva according to the Shaiva Philosophy (Paratrishika, pp 602-3).

KAla, meaning time has also three forms known as Tri-KAla : Past, present and future. KAla is also a name of Lord Shiva.

**We can conclude that Trika-Agni-kAla means the One Who manifests Himself in three different forms of Fire and Time or as 'Trika', Fire and Time.**

Comment: You have read complete Tantraloka ?

Comment: @Pratimaputra - Can you please elaborate on the meanings of Garhpatya, Ahvaniya and Dakshin Agnis? Also, you said: "We can conclude that Trika-Agni-kAla means the One Who manifests Himself in three different forms of Fire and Time or as 'Trika', Fire and Time." Does this mean Trikagnikala should be interpreted as Trikagni and Trikala separately? Please clarify.

Comment: @ Sameer Anand These are different types of Agnis of the Vedic worship.The fire to the right side being named dakshina etc. Please consultvsanskritdictionary.com for the details.The answer to the second question is yes, trika refers to both Agni and Kala, as per the samasa ruoe of sanskrit .

Comment: @SameerAnand I hv replied to your query

Answer (score 2):

Śrī Rudram of the YajurVedā says:

> nama̍ste astu bhagavan viśveśva̱rāya̍ mahāde̱vāya̍ tryamba̱kāya̍
> tripurānta̱kāya̍ **trikāgnikā̱lāya̍** kālāgniru̱drāya̍ nīlaka̱nthāya̍
> mrutyuñja̱yāya̍ sarveśva̱rāya̍ sadāśi̱vāya̍ śrīmanmahāde̱vāya̱ nama̍"
> ||

I offer my salutations (namaste) to Lord Shiva: who is the Lord of the Universe
(viśveśvarā); who is the great God (mahā-devā); who has three eyes (tryambakā); who is the
annihilator of Tripura – the city of the demon; Tripura also represents our ego (tripura
antaka); **who is the master of sacrificial fire of three kinds (trikāgnikālāya)**; who is the
Rudra who consumes everything as the fire of kāla -agni at the time of destruction; One
whose throat is blue (nīla-kanthā); who is the conqueror of death (mrutyuñjayā); who is the
Lord of all (sarveśvara); who is always auspicious (sadā-śiva). Salutations to Rudra who is
the celebrated and great God (śrīman-mahādevā)

Source: Translations and additional commentaries by Dr. R.L. Kashyap from SAKSI (Sri Aurobindo Kapali Sastry Institute of Vedic Culture), Bangalore, India